# How to disable `R_NO_REMAP` when calling R's C `"Rinterals.h"`

Tags: r, c

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 calling R's backend `"Rinternals.h"` and noticed that the `R_NO_REMAP` macro flags won't undefine. The flag suppresses the aliases that removes the `Rf_` prefixes. For example if I translate this file:

```c
//r_extern_c.c
#include "R.h"
#undef R_NO_REMAP //has no effect
#include "Rinternals.h"
#include "R_ext/Rdynload.h"
```

using this

```
gcc -E -P r_extern_c.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags libR` > r_extern.c
```

whether I add the line `#undef R_NO_REMAP` or not has no effect, I still don't get the aliases defined, so for example I have to call `Rf_allocMatrix` rather than `allocMatrix`. It looks like `R_NO_REMAP` definition is being redefined somewhere but I don't know where. I've tried appending `-UR_NO_REMAP` to the command with no effect also. How do I fix this?

Also:

```
gcc --version
# gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

and

```
R --version
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The aliases *are* defined, and you don’t even need the `undef`. However, `gcc -E -P` won’t tell you this, since it *expands* all macros, and doesn’t include macro definitions. Use `gcc -E -dM` instead:

```sh
gcc -E -dM r_extern_c.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libR) >defs.c

grep acopy_string defs.c # for example
# #define acopy_string Rf_acopy_string
```

So this works, and you don’t even need the `undef` statement, it has no effect (since `R_NO_REMAP` wasn’t defined in the first place).

However, *if* you want to define or undefine `R_NO_REMAP`, you need to do it *before including `R.h`*, since this header (indirectly) includes `Rinternals.h`. Modifying the macro definition after including `R.h` thus never has any effect.

Furthermore, **you absolutely should define `R_NO_REMAP`**. The only reason why this isn’t the default is for backwards compatibility with existing package code. But going forward, there’s no reason against defining the macro. Just consider it part of the regular workflow of including R headers.